# How to debug Silverlight application with multiple browser tabs?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, debugging

I have made a Silverlight application that can be started with deep links. My problem is that I need to debug when I try to open the application in another tab with a deep link.

I use VS 2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the piece of code you trying to debug executes immediately upon opening the tab you could try to defer the execution by adding a delay that would allow you to use Visual Studio's Debug -> Attach to process functionality.